# Вывод данных из Mysql в QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, pymysql, qtextedit, qfont

После нажатия кнопки Показать результат вылетает с ошибкой

```
[{'id': 1, 'ФИО': 'фцв', 'Номер_группы': 'фцв', 'Результат': '2'}, {'id': 2, 'ФИО': 'фцв', 'Номер_группы': 'фцв', 'Результат': '5'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\main11.py", line 107, in new_method
    if ╘╚╬ and ═юьхЁ_уЁєяя√ and ╨хчєы№ЄрЄ:                                   # !!! +++
UnboundLocalError: local variable '╘╚╬' referenced before assignment
```

```
class ResyltatiWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ResyltTest):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(ResyltatiWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `students`")
    
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students ")
        
        
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        print(rows)
        self.connection.commit()

        self.textEdit.setText(str(rows))
        self.pushButtontomain_2.clicked.connect(self.new_method)
        self.pushButtontomain.clicked.connect(self.returnToMain)


    def new_method(self):

            rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:                                               # !!! +++
                    id, ФИО, Номер_группы, Результат = row                        # !!! +++ .values()
            if ФИО and Номер_группы and Результат:                                   # !!! +++
                        self.textEdit.append(                                  # !!! +++
                        f'{id:>3} | {ФИО:>30} | {Номер_группы:>10} | {Результат:>3}'     # !!! +++
                )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Никогда не публикуйте изображения, которые содержат текст программы или какие-либо данные. Их надо предоставлять обычным тестом. 2. Предоставьте, обычным текстом данные `rows`, которые вы получили после выполнения `rows = self.cursor.fetchall()`. 3. Предоставьте, обычным текстом, полный текст ошибки, которую вы получаете. Для этого запустите выше приложение в консоли/терминале/ CMD.

Comment: Вот такую ошибку выдает 
line 96
    id, fio, grup, rez = row                        # !!! +++ .values() 
                                                                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level 
Вот что выдает rows, все что есть в бд, то и выдает
[{'id': 1, 'ФИО': 'фвц', 'Номер_группы': 'цфв', 'Результат': '2'}, {'id': 2, 'ФИО': None, 'Номер_группы': None, 'Результат': '2'}, {'id': 3, 'ФИО': 'вцф', 'Номер_группы': 'фцв', 'Результат': '2'}, {'id': 4, 'ФИО': 'уы', 'Номер_группы': 'цф', 'Результат': '2'},

Comment: Все что вы добавляете для прояснения вашего вопроса, вы должны добавлять в тело вопроса, 
а не в комментарии (текст ошибки должен быть полный). 
Вы прочитали сообщение об ошибке? 
У вас проблема с отступами, видимо вы используете где-то табуляцию, а где-то четыре пробела. 
Проверьте чтобы все уровни отступа были четыре пробела.

Comment: Проверил, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ResyltatiWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):           # ??? , Ui_ResyltTest):
    def __init__(self):                                 # , connection
        super(ResyltatiWindow, self).__init__()
        '''
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.connection = connection
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `students`")
        self.connection.commit()
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        
        self.textEdit.setText(str(rows))
        '''

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.textEdit.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 10))                   # !!! +++
            
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Click me") 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)      

    def pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()

#       ...        
#       rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
#       v^v^
        rows = [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'ФИО': 'Пупкин Вася',
                'Номер_группы': 'группа 1',
                'Результат': 2,
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'ФИО': None,
                'Номер_группы': None,
                'Результат': 2,
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'ФИО': 'Тигровая акула',
                'Номер_группы': 'группа 1',
                'Результат': 1,
            },
            {
                'id': 4,
                'ФИО': 'Tiger Shark',
                'Номер_группы': 'группа 1',
                'Результат': 5,
            },
        ]
        
        for row in rows:                                               # !!! +++
            id, fio, grup, rez = row.values()                          # !!! +++ .values()
            if fio and grup and rez:                                   # !!! +++
                self.textEdit.append(                                  # !!! +++
                    f'{id:>3} | {fio:>30} | {grup:>10} | {rez:>3}'     # !!! +++
                )                                                      # !!! +++
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ResyltatiWindow()
    w.resize(500, 200) 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

Еще раз, пожалуйста без фантазий, замените в своем классе  `ResyltatiWindow` метод `new_method()`:

```
    def new_method(self):

            rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
            for row in rows:                                               # !!! +++
                    id, ФИО, Номер_группы, Результат = row                        # !!! +++ .values()
            if ФИО and Номер_группы and Результат:                                   # !!! +++
                        self.textEdit.append(                                  # !!! +++
                        f'{id:>3} | {ФИО:>30} | {Номер_группы:>10} | {Результат:>3}'     # !!! +++
                )
```

на:

```
    def new_method(self):
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:                                               # !!! +++
            id, fio, grup, rez = row.values()                          # !!! +++ .values()
            if fio and grup and rez:                                   # !!! +++
                self.textEdit.append(                                  # !!! +++
                    f'{id:>3} | {fio:>30} | {grup:>10} | {rez:>3}'     # !!! +++
                )
```

Comment: В отдельной программе предложенное вами работает, но внедрить в свой код у меня не получилось(

Comment: @TigerShark я не понимаю что у вас может не получиться? Все что вам надо сделать - это заменить строку `self.textEdit.setText(str(rows))` на шесть строк начиная со строки `for row in rows:` . Я же выделил их для вас `# !!! +++`

Comment: @TigerShark я добавил обновление в свой ответ, прочитайте внимательно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Comment: @TigerShark пожалуйста, но вы забыли отметить мой ответ и как полезный.